# using componentdidMount() to fetch data from news api but getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a website where there will be a header section where top headlines will be displayed and i am using news api to fetch the headlines and setting the fetched data as a state using componentdidmount()

but when i run the app i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backgroundImage')
    at NewsHeader.render (NewsHeader.js:30:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

and this is my code :

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class NewsHeader extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: true,
      error: '',
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=myapikey`;
      let data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedData = await data.json();

      if (parsedData.articles && parsedData.articles.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ articles: parsedData.articles, loading: false });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      this.setState({ loading: false, error: error.message });
    }
  }
  render() {
    let style = {};
    console.log(this.state.articles);
    if (this.state.articles.urlToImage) {
      style = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.articles.urlToImage})`,
      };
    } else {
      style = {
        backgroundImage: `url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1702957954496-8bba5d73a390?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D)`,
      };
    }
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="container-fluid newshead-height newshead-background-image"
          style={style}
        >
          <div className="conatiner-fluid background-overlay newshead-height ">
            <h2 className="text-center pt-2 text-light">Top Headlines</h2>
            <h5>{this.state.articles.title}</h5>
            <p>{this.state.articles .description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

console:

[data is getting printed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alMk8.jpg)

and if i try to access the data from the state in this way (this.state.articles[0].urlToImage) i am getting an error so i changed it to (this.state.articles.urlToImage) to show the output

Comment: The error means that `this.state.articles[0]` is `undefined`, which will happen when the array is empty.

Comment: Your react components' state will initially have an empty state, where the first article isn't available.  You have to build something that can capture this state. Like `return null` if there are no articles.  But it all depends on your use-case. You can also return a `loading...` text while data is being fetched.

Comment: I am gettng the data from the api and the state is also getting updated but when i try to acess the data from state i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

In cases where there is no data, you should keep the previous state or assign an empty array.

```
  if (parsedData.articles && parsedData.articles.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ articles: parsedData.articles, loading: false });
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, loading: false }});
      }
```

or empty array

```
else {
        this.setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, articles:[],loading: false }});
      }
```

Comment: i am getting the data back from the api i will update the question

Comment: this.state.articles is array not object. you cannot access urlToImage from this.state.articles. And please you write as edit of your edits

Comment: Yes, but when i try to use this.state.articles[n].urlToImage i am getting the error but when i use this.state.articles.urlToImage the page is getting rendered with dummy image

Comment: Did you add the solution I posted?

Comment: so sorry for the late reply, I have tried your solution but I am still facing the same error. I am thinking of using a different API the problem might be cause of the request limit by the API. I really thank you for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the methods I can think of but this is the only way that is working for me

declaring individual variable's for all the data I need and getting the articles into a variable from the state and check for the data availability and assigning the data to the respective variable

[working page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfttJ.jpg)

```js
        import { Component } from 'react';
    
    export default class NewsHeader extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          articles: [],
          loading: true,
          error: '',
        };
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=apikey`;
          let data = await fetch(url);
          let parsedData = await data.json();
    
          if (parsedData.articles && parsedData.articles.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ articles: parsedData.articles, loading: false });
          } else {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              return { ...prevState, loading: false };
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          this.setState({ loading: false, error: error.message });
        }
      }
      render() {
        let style = {};
        let articles = this.state.articles;
        let title = 'something went wrong ';
        let description = 'something went wrong';
        let backgroundImage =
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1702957954496-8bba5d73a390?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D';
        if (articles.length >= 1) {
          if (articles[4].title) {
            title = articles[4].title;
          }
          if (articles[4].urlToImage) {
            backgroundImage = articles[4].urlToImage;
          }
          if (articles[4].description) {
            description = articles[4].description;
          }
        } else {
        }
        style = {
          backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        };
        return (
          <>
            <div
              className="container-fluid newshead-height newshead-background-image"
              style={style}
            >
              <div className="conatiner-fluid background-overlay newshead-height ">
                <h2 className="text-center pt-2 text-light">Top Headlines</h2>
                <h5 className="text-light">
                  <strong>{title}</strong>
                </h5>
                <p className="text-light">{description}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

this is not the optimal way of getting it to work but this is the one that seems to be working in my case